# Concrete subclass that does not override abstract methods from abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, overriding

Say that I have two, abstract methods in an abstract base class:

```
    protected abstract void writeData(OutputStream stream);
    protected abstract void writeData(Writer writer);
```

When I make an implementation, I have to override these methods so that when the data needs to be written, it knows how to do it.
What I need to know is if I can make a subclass only need to override ONE of the methods, instead of both of them.
Also, I want to know how to figure out which one of the methods is overrided.
Is this even possible?

Comment: You can override just one of them - but then the subclass has to be abstract as well. I suspect you can find out what's being overridden via reflection, but that sounds like a different question and one which you should ask separately with more context.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the subclass to be abstract, because then I would have to override the missing method when I instantiate it.

Comment: I don't see what you mean - and I'm not sure that you're really clear on what abstract classes are. You don't have to override missing methods when you *instantiate* the class, unless you're using an anonymous inner class. It's very unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: [Interface segregation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle): Don't force your clients to depend on methods they won't use. Create smaller interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is : An `abstract` method in an `abstract` class must be `overridden` in a sub-class. If you wan't to override only one of these methods in your subclass, the subclass will have to be declared as `abstract` as well. Such a subclass is pretty much useless if it does not have any `static` fields or methods because it cannot be instantiated and you cannot access instance fields or methods without an instance of the class.

That being said, Java 8 introduces the concept of default methods in an `interface`. You could convert your abstract class into an `interface` and mark `writeData(OutputStream stream)` and `writeData(Writer writer)` as `default` :

```
public interface DataWriter {
    public default void writeData(OutputStream stream) {
        //no-behavior
    }

    public default void writeData(Writer writer) {
        //no-behavior
    }
}
```

The above code is similar to an abstract class and different from a concrete class because it cannot be instantiated. While this solves your problem,I really don't see much value in doing something like this in the first place.

Comment: I actually was thinking of doing this, but thought it wouldn't work, but now that I think of it, it just might. Thanks!

Comment: @MrabEzreb I wouldn't recommend you to do something like this. This answer was aimed at asking you not to do something like this.

Comment: :P still, if I do need to have both methods (which after looking through my code, I am starting to think that I don't) this would work.

Answer (score 2):

A concrete subclass must override all `abstract` methods, or it must be changed to be `abstract` itself.  You can't override just one if there are multiple `abstract` methods.

For your requirements, it doesn't make sense to have a concrete subclass override just one of the overloaded `abstract` methods.  You can try having only *one* `writeData` method in your abstract superclass, with a generic type parameter.

```
public abstract class MyClass<T extends Closeable & Flushable>
{
    protected abstract void writeData(T t);
}
```

I've added upper bounds that represent the common interfaces between `OutputStream` and `Writer`, but they generally aren't necessary.

Then your concrete subclasses, which need to override only one method, can choose which type parameter to utilize.

```
class MyOutputStreamClass extends MyClass<OutputStream>
{
    protected void writeData(OutputStream stream) { /* implement */ }
}

class MyWriterClass extends MyClass<Writer>
{
    protected void writeData(Writer writer) { /* implement */ }
}
```

Comment: This is elegant. However, what advantage does it have over creating a concrete class with two `overloaded` methods or what advantage does it have over creating two unrelated concrete classes with methods that take different parameters? I believe the OP did not want to split the methods across multiple classes or subclasses.

Comment: @ChetanKinger This technique doesn't have a useless `default` method inherited in each concrete subclass.  That would be confusing to a user who might call a method on a superclass reference expecting it to do something, and it does nothing.  Having 2 overloaded methods would lead to an expectation that both methods have functionality.

Comment: I don't believe my question was "how is your answer better than mine" so I am not sure why there was a need to refer to my answer.  I answered exactly what the OP asked and also added a disclaimer saying that there is no real value in doing what I have suggested. I commented on your answer out of curiosity and not for competing with your answer. As a matter of fact, I upvoted your answer even before anyone upvoted mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is declare only one method as abstact method. The method you don't want subclass to override, you can provide its implementation in this abstract class.

Something like this:

```
protected abstract void writeData(OutputStream stream);

//the method you don't want subclass to override.
public void writeData(Writer writer)
{ 
     //doSomething here 
}
```